# Get all stl vector elements greater than a value

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I would like to know how can I find the list of a stl vector elements that have value verifying a certain condition. For example if I have a vector of int values

```
vector<int> V;
```

and I want to get all the elements that are greater than 5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd `std::copy_if()` if the values:

```
std::vector<int> target;
std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(target),
             std::bind(std::less<int>(), 5, _1));
```

Comment: or, `std::erase_if`, and reverse the condition, to rearrange the original container.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I guess, you mean the combination of `erase()` and `std::remove_if()`, i.e., `v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(std::less_equal<int>(), _1, 5), v.end()));`

Comment: @DietmarKühl Can you please explain the use of std::bind. Thanks

Comment: @tuxworker: sure: `std::bind()` is used for [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying): the first argument of `std::less<int>()` is bound to `5` and the second argument becomes the first argument of the call to the function object produced by `std::bind()`. A full-blown explanation is probably a question on its own, one which probably is already answered on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @DietmarKühl v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(std::less_equal<int>(), _1, 5), v.end())); Does this erase the elements that are less or equal than 5 in the original container ? Thanks

Comment: @tuxworker: Yes, this is the intention. `std::remove_if()` shuffles all elements for which the predicate is `true` to the front of the sequence. `std::vector<...>::erase()` actually removes the elements from the container. I'm not entirely sure if I got the condition right, though.

Comment: Oh, when I made the comment, I hadn't meant to actually erase them, merely use `remove_if` to make the wanted elements to the beginning.  I guess you could erase them too

Comment: @MooingDuck Actually I would like to remove them too :)

Comment: @MooingDuck: well, there is no `std::erase_if()` ;) ... and I recall a major issue I created in production code due to forgetting to `erase()` the `std::remove_if()`ed elements of a `std::vector<T>`: the vector kept growing and eventually the `std::remove_if()` was spending its time searching for non-removed elements in removed elements.

Comment: @DietmarKühl when I used bind I've got this error `error: bind is not a member of std `

Comment: `std::bind()` is declared in `<functional>`. It is a C++ 2011 feature. If you don't have C++ 2011 you can use `std::bind1st()` and `std::bind2nd()` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to get the found elements positions in the vector

Comment: You'd use `std::find()` or `std::find_if()`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I use `find_if()`