# get all vector elements greater than a value c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of float like:

```
vector<float> v = [0.4 0.2 0.8 0.1 0.5 0.6];
```

I would like to create a new vector (call it target):

```
vector<float> target;
```

containg only those elements greater than 0.5. I tried this line from  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978216/get-all-stl-vector-elements-greater-than-a-value)

```
copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(target), bind(less<float>(), 0.5, placeholders::_1));
```

but when I try to print out the elements in target, I obtain always the first element for n times (with n number of element inside v greater than 0.5).

the print is done in this way:

```
for (auto i = target.begin(); i != target.end(); ++i) {
    cout << target[*i] << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you print your vector?

Comment: in this way:
 for (auto i = target.begin(); i != target.end(); ++i) {
        cout << '--------------- \t' << target[*i] << '\t' << endl;}

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccf610644538f6ce)

Comment: Your output routine makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lambda to do it easily

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
   vector<float> v {0.4,0.2,0.8,0.1,0.5,0.6};
   vector<float> target;
   copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(target),[](float n ){ return  n > 0.5;});
   for (auto i = target.begin(); i != target.end(); i++) {
    cout << *i << endl;
}
}
```

Output

```
0.8
0.6
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=230e78d1fb01482c)

Answer (score 6):

In your output, `i` is an iterator. `target[*i]` will print the element at the position equal to the element at `i`'s position. Since your values are all less than 1 and greater than 0, `*i` always equals 0. This leads to printing the element as position 0 a number of times equal to the number of elements in your vector.

Try the following instead :

```
for (auto i = target.begin(); i != target.end(); ++i) {
    cout << *i << endl;
}
```

Or simply :

```
for (auto i : target) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: ok now it works.....and I want also the indeces on v of those elements?

Comment: @alexmark That's a different question that can't easily be answered here.